# Is there a way to create desktop shortcuts (.url files) with Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I recently noticed one way in which TorBrowser acts differently than stock Firefox - I can't drag from the address bar to an Explorer window.  In stock Firefox, this would allow me to create a shortcut (.url) file pointing to the current Web page in the destination folder; but with TorBrowser, this doesn't work - which means that I'm reduced to using a tedious and error-prone cut and paste procedure.

I assume that this is considered to enhance security somehow, but if I'm aware of the security implications of leaving .url files around in places where other people might find them, shouldn't I be able to flip a switch somewhere in the Tor configuration to re-enable this functionality?

Comment: What OS are you using? I guess Windows.

Comment: Yes, this is Windows.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?